# The meaning of ?retryWrites=true&w=majority when you connect Node.js app to Cluster on MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

When we connect a Node.js application to a cluster on the mongoDB Atlas, we need to add the following URI instead of adding `"mongodb://localhost:27017/<dbname>"` as you can see at the step 2 in the image.

```
"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster1.tv7cp.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Now, what exactly the meaning of `?retryWrites=true&w=majority` in it after `<dbname>`? Why do we need to add it?

I tried and ran the app with mongoose without `?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, and it worked fine.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`Retryable writes` allows MongoDB drivers to **automatically retry certain write operations** a single time if they encounter network errors, or if they cannot find a healthy primary in the replica sets or sharded cluster.

`Write concern` describes the level of acknowledgment requested from MongoDB for **write operations to a standalone mongod or to replica sets or to sharded clusters**. In sharded clusters, mongos instances will pass the write concern on to the shards.
( if your replica set has 3 members that mean that your majority=2 , meaning that your write operation will receive acknowledgment after it receive success confirmation from at least 2 members)

Comment: and if you leave the parameters off, it will still connect to the database, but use some defaults: no automatic retries, and probably a lower level of acknowledgement (such as primary-only)